# How to get the outermost command evaluated first?

Tags: programming, syntax, built-in-symbols

I have an expression like ToString[Stuff[...]]. I plan on having the Stuff[...] be manipulated as a string according to the output of other parts of the program. The problem is that Mathematica tries to evaluate the Stuff[...] first and since the expression is not yet complete it just returns an error.

I can't just use "Stuff[...]" because there are actually *other* incomplete ToString[...] expressions inside Stuff[...] and Mathematica interprets the nested "A "B" C" as two separate strings with some evaluable expression in the middle.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Here's a little piece of toy code I'm trying to get working:

ToString[Flatten[
  Array[StringJoin["(", ToString[(-1)^#1], ",", ToString[(-1)^#2], 
     ")"] &, {2, 2}]]]

Comment: Could you give a small working example?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Sure, I'll add a little toy piece of the code I'm trying to get working to the main text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Defer` or `HoldForm` in the first argument and `StandardForm` in the last argument of the outer `ToString`:

```
ToString[Defer@Flatten[Array[StringJoin["(", ToString[(-1)^#1], ",",
                       ToString[(-1)^#2], ")"] &, {2, 2}]], StandardForm]
(*  "Flatten[Array["("<>ToString[(-1)^#1]<>","<>ToString[(-1)^#2]<>")"&,{2,2}]]" *)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :-)

Comment: @quantum_loser, my pleasure. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is interested I've come up with a rather inelegant solution. That is replacing the inner-most strings with per-defined definitions of those strings, therefore avoiding the problem of the nested quotation marks. In the example I gave the solution would be

P1 = "(";

P2 = ")";

c = ",";

"Flatten[Array[StringJoin[P1,ToString[(-1)^#1],c,ToString[(-1)^#2],P2]&\
,{2,2}]]"

Would still love to see a more general solution to the problem if anyone can find one ;-)

Comment: How does this differ from what you wrote in your question? I get "{(-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1)}" in both cases...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That's odd, because I don't. I get the string I want. What version of Mathematica are you running? I am running 10.

Comment: Same here, MMA 10 on OS X 10.9. Btw, is the backslash after & in the last expression a typo? I assumed it was.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes, it's a typo. Very odd we don't get the same thing. Only difference I can think of is that I'm running the windows version.